# PHP variable scope - setting globals inside foreach loops

Tags: php, scope, global

I am new-ish to PHP have read the [PHP Variable scope docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) and [other Stackoverflow threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626812/are-php-variables-declared-inside-a-foreach-loop-destroyed-and-re-created-at-eac) and can't get my head around why setting a global var inside a foreach loop doesn't work:

```
if (isset($regionsArr) && $page == 'regions') {
  $param = htmlspecialchars($_GET["region"]);
  foreach ($regionsArr as $item) {
    if ($item['region'] == $param) {
      global $curRegion;
      $curRegion = $item;
      echo $GLOBALS["curRegion"]["name"]; // works
    } else {
      $curRegion = null;
    }
  }
}
if (isset($GLOBALS["curRegion"])) {
  echo $GLOBALS["curRegion"]["name"]; // does not work
}
```

Comment: `$GLOBALS["curRegion"]` is `$curRegion`, guess your overriding it subsequent iterations of the foreach, you can use just `$curRegion`, then once matched just `break;` out of the foreach so its not overwritten

Comment: @LawrenceCherone You are a savior. The `break;` was all it took. Many thanks for not voting this down! :)

Comment: np, you can do away with most of your code by using array_filter, array_reduce or array_column, array_search etc https://3v4l.org/mZ02t

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thank you sir. PS... if you happen to watch Silicon Valley, my brother Matt played Gavin Belson :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @lawrencecherone for pointing out that I need to `break;` out of the loop.

Without the brake, the loop continues and overrides `$curRegion` with null after it is successfully set in the loop.

Note: if by stroke of luck your matched `$item` happened to be the very last item in the loop, then it wouldn't get overridden, but... yeah... just add break;

```
foreach ($regionsArr as $item) {
  if ($item['region'] == $param) {
    $curRegion = $item;
    break; // this kills the loop after $item['region'] matches $param
  } else {
    $curRegion = null;
  }
}
```

I believe there is a more condensed way to do the above using array_filter or another method, and I welcome it as the solution.